# can saveToCassandra() work with multiple tables

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

i have rdd contains four lines look like this :

```
Stock(test1,2017/07/23 00:01:02,14,Status)
Stock(test1,2017/07/23 00:01:03,78,Status)
Stock(test2,2017/07/23 00:01:02,86,Status)
Stock(test2,2017/07/23 00:01:03,69,Status)
Stock(test3,2017/07/23 00:01:02,46,Status)
Stock(test3,2017/07/23 00:01:03,20,Status)
```

which test1,test2,test3 are the tables names, i ask if it possible to save this rdd in this three tables ?
thansk

Comment: I am not familiar with saveToCassandra but can't you filter your rdd based on the first column in your case class `Stock`, then get 3 different RDDs on which you can use `saveToCassandra`?

Comment: i ask if can  i get only first line and seconde one and save them in table "test1", 3th and 4th lines into table "test2", 5th and 6th lines into table "test3" ?
i have three topics kafka test1,test2,test3 ( topic name=table name), i have stream data from these topics i ask if it possible to filter the stream data of topic "test1"  can go into table "test1", etc

Comment: You should not use save option of dataframe. Rather check out the first column of  each line of Kafka messages, then initialize the table name accordingly and insert the data.

Comment: hi @ishan i don't know how can i insert data into table without using saveToCassandra()